# what is this anonymous block in javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, block

I am reading about new ES6 features from [pragmatists](https://blog.pragmatists.com/top-10-es6-features-by-example-80ac878794bb). but here as you can see that they used an *anonymous block* in that function.
Can someone please explain what is meaning of that. Is it any javascript object or what? How can we use that? Please also mention some reference for that.

```js
function f() {
  var x = 1
  let y = 2
  const z = 3
  {
    var x = 100
    let y = 200
    const z = 300
    console.log('x in block scope is', x)
    console.log('y in block scope is', y)
    console.log('z in block scope is', z)
  }
  console.log('x outside of block scope is', x)
  console.log('y outside of block scope is', y)
  console.log('z outside of block scope is', z)
}

f()
```

Comment: It’s just a block (statement), used for organization and scoping of “let”. The syntax has been around since the inception of JS although most useful since “let” was introduce. The scope of “var” is *always* that of the function. Search for “javascript variable hoisting”.

Comment: It is so clear that block is used for scope the variables. Just check output values and you will understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block):

> The block statement is often called **compound statement** in other languages. It allows you to use multiple statements where JavaScript expects only one statement. Combining statements into blocks is a common practice in JavaScript. The opposite behavior is possible using an empty statement, where you provide no statement, although one is required.
>
> Blocks are commonly used in association with `if...else` and `for` statements.

Based on your example:

```js
function f() {
  const z = 3
  
    const z = 300
  
  console.log('z outside of block scope is', z)
}

f()
```

Without using block scope we get error like:

> SyntaxError: redeclaration of const z

And with block scope:

```js
function f() {
  const z = 3
  {
    const z = 300
    console.log('z in block scope is', z)
  }
  console.log('z outside of block scope is', z)
}

f()
```

same code works fine. Note that the block-scoped `const z = 300` does not throw a *SyntaxError* because it can be declared uniquely within the block.

Answer (score 3):

Anonymous blocks are helpful when using let variable. Variables declared by `var` keyword are scoped to the immediate function body while `let` variables are scoped to the immediate enclosing block denoted by { }.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a bare block. Any time you encounter a bare block, you can consider it equivalent to:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  // block contents here
}
```

or

```
if (true) {
  // block contents here
}
```

It's nothing special, and rarely used. The most important part of it is probably how `const` and `let` variables declared within it are scoped *only to the block*, and not to the outer function.

It has the same sort of behavior as all non-function blocks in Javascript - just like an `if` block, or a `while` block, or a `for` block, except that there's no condition to enter it, and it's executed exactly once.